# spring data cassandra saving only a single object in the list

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

**Model**

```
    @Table(value = "bad_data")
    public class BadData {
        private String objectID;
        private String type;
        private String problems;
        private String owner;
        private String formattedID;
        private String project;

    @PrimaryKey
    private String train;
    private String status;

    /* Default constructor. */
    public BadData () {
        this.objectID = "";
        this.type = "";
        this.problems = "";
        this.owner = "";
        this.formattedID = "";
        this.project = "";
        this.train = "";
        this.status = "";
    }


    /* Getters and setters. */
    public void setObjectID (String objectID) {
        this.objectID = objectID;
    }

    public String getObjectID () {
        return this.objectID;
    }

    public void setType (String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType () {
        return this.type;
    }

    public void setProblems (String problems) {
        this.problems = problems;
    }

    public String getProblems () {
        return this.problems;
    }

    public void setOwner (String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public String getOwner () {
        return this.owner;
    }

    public void setFormattedID (String formattedID) {
        this.formattedID = formattedID;
    }

    public String getFormattedID () {
        return this.formattedID;
    }

    public void setProject (String project) {
        this.project = project;
    }

    public String getProject () {
        return this.project;
    }

    public void setTrain (String train) {
        this.train = train;
    }

    public String getTrain () {
        return this.train;
    }

    public void setStatus (String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus () {
        return this.status;
    }

}
```

**Repository**

```
@Autowired
public void save (CassandraOperations db) {
        BadData badData1 = new BadData();
        badData1.setTrain("train");
        badData1.setFormattedID("fid");
        badData1.addProblems("problem1");
        badData1.setObjectID("id");
        badData1.setOwner("lokesh");
        badData1.setType("story");
        badData1.setProject("om");
        badData1.setStatus("open");

        BadData badData2 = new BadData();
        badData2.setTrain("train");
        badData2.setFormattedID("fid");
        badData2.addProblems("problem2");
        badData2.setObjectID("id");
        badData2.setOwner("lokesh");
        badData2.setType("story");
        badData2.setProject("om");
        badData2.setStatus("open");

        BadData badData3 = new BadData();
        badData3.setTrain("train");
        badData3.setFormattedID("fid");
        badData3.addProblems("problem3");
        badData3.setObjectID("id");
        badData3.setOwner("lokesh");
        badData3.setType("story");
        badData3.setProject("om");
        badData3.setStatus("open");

        List<BadData> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(badData1);
        data.add(badData3);
        data.add(badData2);

        db.insert(data);
    }
```

I am trying to save three objects placing them in list. I got only one object (badData3) saved into the database. I changed the order of those objects in the list. i noticed that which ever object is in the middle of the list is getting saved. Can some one guess what could be the possible error be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@PrimaryKey` is train field, and you set this field in each object to the same value: `"train"` so they will override each other.

Answer (score 2):

Yes ([krsyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48382/krzyk) is correct), the value ("train") of your `@PrimaryKey` field (`train`) is the same for all entities in your List.

Also, you should have a look at the corresponding test case ([insertBatchTest](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/1.4.x/spring-data-cassandra/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/cassandra/test/integration/template/CassandraDataOperationsTest.java#L182-L208)) in test class (`CassandraDataOperationsTest`) in the *SD Cassandra* test suite.

For reassurance, I added the following code snippet to the end of the test...

`assertThat(template.count(Book.class), is(equalTo(80l)));`

And, the test passed as expected.

Note, I was using the latest *Spring Data Cassandra* `1.4.2.RELEASE`.

Also note, because every `INSERT` or `UPDATE` in *Cassandra* is actually an "`UPSERT`" (see [here](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/how-to-do-an-upsert-in-cassandra/)), then you are effectively overwriting each entry (entity) in your List because of the duplicate primary key value.